# homework / sqlite3 avg outcome strange

Tags: sqlite, join, average, sql-limit

My task is to write a a SQL query to determine the average rating of all movies released in 2012 using an imdb movies.db file.

The values for this query are in two tables:

Table 1 MOVIES /
**id** INTEGER /
**title** TEXT NOT NULL /
**year** NUMERIC

Table 2 RATINGS /
**movie_id** INTEGER NOT NULL /
**rating** REAL NOT NULL /
**votes** INTEGER NOT NULL

My method is to approach the desired outcome step by step. So at the moment I have a list - limited for better overview - of ratings of movies released in 2012. I've wanted to count the average of these ratings and since the outcome was wrong I've checked it for sum and I got a very strange number.

Could anyone explain me what is happening here?

[picture of code and outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbAA4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query:

```
SELECT SUM(rating)
FROM ratings JOIN movies 
ON ratings.movie_id = movies.id
WHERE year = 2012
```

as it is, without `LIMIT`, returns only 1 row which is the sum of **all** the ratings of **all** the movies of 2012.
So applying `LIMIT 15` does not affect the result.

If you want the sum of 15 ratings you should do:

```
SELECT SUM(rating)
FROM (
  SELECT ratings.rating
  FROM ratings JOIN movies 
  ON ratings.movie_id = movies.id
  WHERE year = 2012
  LIMIT 15
)
```

which will get only 15 ratings with the subquery and then return their sum.

The same applies to the average:

```
SELECT AVG(rating)
FROM (
  SELECT ratings.rating
  FROM ratings JOIN movies 
  ON ratings.movie_id = movies.id
  WHERE year = 2012
  LIMIT 15
)
```

In any case using `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` clause is not a good choice, because you never know which rows will be returned, so the result is undefined.
So it would be better to sort the rows, say by the movie's id and then apply the `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT AVG(rating)
FROM (
  SELECT ratings.rating
  FROM ratings JOIN movies 
  ON ratings.movie_id = movies.id
  WHERE year = 2012
  ORDER BY movies.id LIMIT 15
)
```